# How to use CVX to solve this problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, computational-geometry, cvx

I have a function in the variables $x_{kl};\ k,l=1\ldots,m$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1,j<j'}^{N_i}\left( b_{ij} b_{ij'}- \sum_{k,l=1}^{m}x_{kl}f_k(a_{ij})f_l(a_{ij'})\right)^2$$

where $a_{ij},b_{ij}$ are known constants and $f_k$ are known functions. Moreover, we must let $x_{kl}=x_{lk}$. How can I solve this using CVX, or is there an (easy for those who have experience, because this looks a little bit like the least squares estimator) expression for the solution? Can I use CVX if the unkown is a matrix?

Comment: If you write the $x_{ij}$s as a long vector, the optimality conditions will result in a set of normal equations. No need to bring in the big guns.

Comment: the difficulty is the bijection to go from $kl,k\leq l$ to $\{1,\ldots, m(m+1)/2\}$

Comment: CVX can accept the form as it is, although I am not quite convinced that your objective function is convex.

Comment: It's just a quadratic in $x$, so that's fine, it's convex. Here's the thing: suppose you were given a *constant* vector $x$ and tasked with computing the value of this objective function. How would you write it in MATLAB? If you can answer that question, then it's quite likely you have answered that question for CVX, too. But more importantly, *it's just a structured least squares problem*, so you shouldn't need to use CVX at all.